# Automatic disambiguation advice for ambiguous tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'm fairly active in answering questions with the [flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) tag. During the last months I'm stumbling more and more about question which are wrongly tagged with `flex`, which is comprehensible because the "flex" term is an often used substring for names of other frameworks or libraries (flexbox, flex-lexer, flexslider, flexjson).

Typically the ambiguous usage of the flex tag is done by newbies and even though the tag excerpts are shown under the "tags" input box they are sometimes ignoring or overseeing it. But often there exist conjunctions to other tags like in the following examples:

- [flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) + [actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript) = Apache Flex question
- [flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) + [flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) = Apache Flex question
- [flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) + [bison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bison) = ambiguous usage of flex → [flex-lexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex-lexer) + [bison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bison)
- [flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) + [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) = ambiguous usage of flex → [flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox) + [bison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bison)

My suggestion is to extend the tag wikis with an input field for "blacklist" and/or "whitelist" tag names which are used for a disambiguation advice. So if the user types "flex" "css3" then (for example) a red tooltip pops up that the tag "flex" is most likely misused and the tag "flexbox" should be used instead.

This offers an general approach to minimize the wrong usage of ambiguous tags at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm not sure ...feeling like this might be overkill... tags are important, however how would this extra `input field for "blacklist" and/or "whitelist" tag names which are used for a disambiguation advice` actually appear like ?  Further,  I feel as if tags would not be the only problem in these poorly-constructed questions

Comment: @Coffee the input field should appear on the tag wiki page, where the trusted wiki users could edit them.

Comment: Related: [People don't read the tag excerpts because we don't swat them into their faces](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114) btw, my stance is, tags should be unambiguous in name and usage. Rename [flex] to something else.

Comment: @Braiam renaming flex could lead to even more confusion for experienced flex questioners and it would probably not solve the ambiguousness and misusage of the "flex" term.

Comment: How so? If they aren't getting confused already from seeing questions they know nothing about?

Comment: @Braiam That's not really how people work, though. You'd think that people would make sure the tags were right, but they do not. Whatever "flexbox" is, folks using it are probably just calling it "flex" in context, which is fair enough. The "unique tag name" boat has sailed... and the question is, how do we deal with that?

Comment: I'm not sure that a static blacklist/whitelist type of thing is the way to go here, but this is an interesting idea. Some sort of tag groupings? "Tag clouds"? I'm not sure anything fully automatic that's not vetted by a human could really work here... but then, I tend to be biased against fully automated systems when it comes to freeform-ish user input. Worth exploring when/if we have time, IMO.

Comment: @AnnaLear "how do we deal with that?" There are two alternatives: renaming, something that any user can do within time; and tag tips, which require developer intervention. I prefer to do what can be done, and not complicate the tag system more than it is with this idea (which is not new in principle, and has been rejected before).